# how to group json array of object based on objects array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, arraylist, javascript-objects

I have a complex json of objects and array, I want to change that based on tags,I tried multiple solution, but I am unable to fix it.I tried the logic group by josn but that is not working in my case.
my json object =

```
[{
    "name": "dummy ttile11 house?"
    "tag": ["hospital", "car", "church"]
}, {
    "name": "dummy ttile1 44"
    "tag": ["car", "home", "office"]
}, {
    "name": "dummy ttile11 5546"
    "tag": ["friend", "teacher", "schools"]
}, {
    "name": "dummy ttle"
    "tag": ["father", "friend", "mother"]
}, {
    "name": "dummy ter"
    "tag": ["hospital", "mother", "home"]
}, {
    "name": "dummy tret"
    "tag": ["car", "home", "church"]
}, {
    "name": "dummy ttile11"
    "tag": ["hospital", "school", "library"]
}]
```

I want to change it to like:

```
hospital:[title:"ttile",title:"title",title:"title",title:"title",title:"title"],
car:[title:"ttile",title:"title",title:"title"],
church:[title:"ttile",title:"title",],
home:[title:"ttile",title:"title",title:"title",title:"title"],
office:[title:"ttile",title:"title",title:"title"],
friend:[title:"ttile",title:"title",title:"title"],
teacher:[title:"ttile",title:"title",title:"title"],
school:[title:"ttile",title:"title",title:"title"],
father:title:"ttile",title:"title",title:"title"],
mother:[title:"ttile",title:"title",title:"title"]
```

Comment: This makes no sense (and is impossible): `office:{title:"title1",title:"title2",title:"title3"}`. Do you mean `office: ["title1","title2","title3"]`?

Comment: yes sir like office: ["title1","title2","title3"]

Comment: @jarmod sir I update the question

Comment: Hi, did you write any code to attempt to solve this? Please include your latest code (after fixing any syntax errors) so that someone can help you correct/improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you an object of tags with their associated titles.

```
let taglist = data.reduce((b, a) => [...b, ...a.tag], []) // accumulate the tags list
      .filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i), // get only the uniques
      // the first part creates the array of unique tags that we can then iterate through
    tags = taglist.map(t => ({ [t]: data.filter(d => d.tag.includes(t)).map(d => d.name) }))
    // this line maps our list of tags into an object that contains all the associated titles
```

```js
const data = [{
  "name": "dummy ttile11 house?",
  "tag": ["hospital", "car", "church"]
}, {
  "name": "dummy ttile1 44",
  "tag": ["car", "home", "office"]
}, {
  "name": "dummy ttile11 5546",
  "tag": ["friend", "teacher", "schools"]
}, {
  "name": "dummy ttle",
  "tag": ["father", "friend", "mother"]
}, {
  "name": "dummy ter",
  "tag": ["hospital", "mother", "home"]
}, {
  "name": "dummy tret",
  "tag": ["car", "home", "church"]
}, {
  "name": "dummy ttile11",
  "tag": ["hospital", "school", "library"]
}]

const exclude = ['teacher','mother', 'school','hospital'];
let taglist = data.reduce((b, a) => [...b, ...a.tag], []).filter((v, i, a) => !exclude.includes(v) && a.indexOf(v) === i),
  tags = taglist.map(t => ({ [t]: data.filter(d => d.tag.includes(t)).map(d => d.name) }))


console.log(tags)
```

Comment: Clever, but could be a maintenance headache for the OP.

Comment: @Kinglish you are the real king, thanks man.

Comment: @Kinglish can I do to exclude some tags. like if the tag is teacher then remove it.

Comment: @usercomapny - updated answer - now you have an `exclude` array to utilize

Comment: @Kinglish thank you so much. it works fine

Comment: @Kinglish can we do like to just push only first two name in array and ignore the other
{
    "car": [
      "dummy ttile11 house?",
      "dummy ttile1 44",
      "dummy tret" //ignore this, bcs i need maximum tow name in each array
    ]
  },